# How to get PyCharm runserver to work with vagrant and heroku run?

Tags: python, django, heroku, pycharm

Normally I execute `heroku run` to set environment variables from a `.env` file. I can't prefix PyCharm's command with `heroku run`. How do I set environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `python` file in the root of your project.
2. Paste this inside

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/env bash
   export $(cat /vagrant/.env | grep -v ^# | xargs)

   /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/virtualenvname/bin/python "$@"
   ```
3. Make it executable `chmod +x python`
4. In pycharm set this file as the python interpreter for the project.

N.B. It needs your variables in .env to be seperated using an equals sign and for there to be no spaces.

eg.

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=abc123abc124
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.local
```